# How to apply an animation color effect on a div

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery function :

```
$('.tracklistOff').find('.trackon').clone().insertAfter(($(param).parents('.trackon')));
```

I clone the div and I add it. The CSS class of `trackon` is :

```
.trackon{width:710px; height:26px; color:#CCCCCC; font-weight:bold; float:left;}
```

I'd like, when I add it, to put a red background color of trackon, and shade it to black; a sort of fadeIn(), without starting from hide (but from red) and finish to the `trackon` background (in my context, should be white).
How can I do it without any plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

It's a plugin, yes, I know. But it's the only way I know how to do it short of rewriting the plugin yourself.

Comment: I can't believe there isn't a method with pure jquery; I see many website using this effect; Would be also ok set the CSS background red at the beginning, and shade it to white...

Comment: That plugin was actually created by John Resig, who created jQuery. I would consider that "pure" :). Most websites that use jQuery probably use that plugin. The others write their own method. It really is a tiny plugin, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: In fact, now that I look at it, it is considered an official plugin

Comment: Downloaded this plug-ins! Now? :)

Comment: Reference it like you would any JavaScript file, and animate like this: `$('#something').animate({backgroundColor: '#400101'})`

Comment: Seems not working; I get the message `cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Make sure you are loading the Color plugin after you load jQuery itself.

Comment: Yeah man I done it ;) `<script type="text/javascript" src="settings/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="settings/jquery.color.js"></script>` but it print that error...

Comment: A few other things to check: Ensure you are doing this is a jQuery `ready` function; Try changing `backgroundColor` to something else like `color`; Add a duration to `animate`

Comment: uhm...it works with `color` but not with `backgroundColor`. So, it change only text, not the background? argh...why?

Comment: I think I'll open a new topic! thanks, this is the right answer anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is an animate-colors plugin for jquery that allows color animation using the normal animation methods. That should do it for you.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery UI extends jQuery's animate method to allow you to modulate colors. Here's a link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

Comment: Jquery UI is a horribly BLOATED addition, adding that much weight for a color animation is a bad idea. It's like the OP wanting an animal for his 5 yr old, and suggesting an elephant. Especially when not wanting to use a plugin in the first place.